# Can't call useMocker on TestingModule

Tags: nestjs, ts-jest, nestjs-testing

I'm trying to execute useMocker on the following piece of code:

```
const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
        providers: [
            RatingService,
            UserService,
            RentService,
            { provide: getRepositoryToken(RatingORM), useValue: repositoryMockFactory(ratingStub()) },
        ],
    }).useMocker((token) => {
        switch(token) {
            case UserService: return UserService;
            case RentService: return RentService;
        }
    }).compile();
```

but I keep getting the error "Property 'useMocker' does not exist on type 'TestingModuleBuilder'"

Anyone knows why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you're using the right version of `@nestjs/testing`. Upgrade it to the latest or something